# The wallet created does not work normally, saying that there is a problem with my network

Tags: web3.js

[image]

The wallet created does not work normally, saying that there is a problem with my network.

Comment: If `fetch` failed, it might mean that your computer does not have an internet connection, or that your computer is not configured to allow node to access the internet. It looks like there are a lot of posts about `UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` so you may want to research that error first